# ASP.Net: How to open a second window and write something in the mainwindow?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to open a window on a button click (favorite is ImageButton) and do some searches there.
The search should be in a grid view and give the information back directly into a textbox.

How is this possible? (best would be without javascript directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client-side Option:**

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("id").value = "whatever";
```

**Server-side Option:**

Postback your window that is open, save the data somewhere so that is retrievable by the other page, emit javascript: `window.opener.submit();self.close();` on it's postback to cause your other page to then postback and the open window to close.  Have your code-behind retrieve the data needed and change your TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put it using javascript
for the image button add this at the server side

```
imgBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick","open_window()")
```

Then Add this Javascript function in the container page

```
   function open_window()
     {
    var item = document.getElementById("txtShow");
     var dataitem = window.open("YourPage.aspx", "dataitem",
 "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes"); 
     dataitem.item = item;

     }
```

in the window add the select function and create a custom link in the grid view

```
   function select_item(name) {
        item.value = name;
        top.close();
    }
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="rowID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Field" HeaderText="Test" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="select_item('<%#Eval("SelectText") %>')">Select</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```